# Is it correct to use comma in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Along the coast of northern California grow huge, towering trees.

Why the comma is between huge and towering?

Comment: Because *huge* and *towering* are being used as coordinate adjectives. It's the same as saying *… grow huge **and** towering trees*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A comma is used between coordinated adjectives, that is, adjectives that describe a noun equally. The distinction between coordinated and cumulative adjectives is explained here:
[Englishplus.com "commas with paired adjectives"](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000072.htm)

> **Commas with Paired Adjectives**
>
> **Coordinate Adjectives**
>
> If two adjectives modify a noun **in the same way**, place a comma between the two adjectives. These are called **coordinate adjectives**.
>
> There is a two-part test for coordinate adjectives:
>
> (1) Can you replace the comma with the word **and**?
>
> (2) Can you reverse the order of the adjectives and keep the same meaning?
>
> If you can do both, then you have coordinate adjectives.
>
> - **Correct**: Did you read about Macomber's short, happy life?
> - **Test for Correctness**: Did you read about Macomber's short and happy life?
> - Did you read about Macomber's happy, short life?
>
> All three sentences say the same thing, so the adjectives are coordinate adjectives and separated by commas in the original.
>
> **Cumulative Adjectives**
>
> If the paired adjectives fail the two-part test, then no comma is used. This shows that they must remain in a certain order to make sense. These are called **cumulative adjectives**.
>
> - **Incorrect**: The former, overweight woman told us how she lost fifty-five pounds.
> - **Test for Correctness**: The former and overweight woman...
>   (Makes no sense)
> - The overweight, former woman...
>   (A former woman? At best the meaning is changed.)
>
> Clearly, no comma is needed for these cumulative adjectives.
>
> - **Correct**: The former overweight woman told us how she lost fifty-five pounds.
>
> A device to help remember this punctuation rule is to keep in mind a common expression like *Christmas tree or fire truck*. We say, "green Christmas tree," but not "Christmas green tree." We say, "red fire truck," but not "fire red truck." Such cumulative expressions take no comma.

Comment: Someone has copied the entire contents of the linked page here, a page with a clear copyright notice. Doesn't that amount to plagiarism, as opposed to "fair use"?